# Getting Connection Error Connection Must Be Valid and Open

Tags: mysql, asp.net

This is my Data access layer but i don't know why i am getting connection error when multi user using and when more than 1 user access the website i checked all thing but cant fix it i am posting my code. this is updated code. it again stuck and result same as last code. i dnt know why it happened when more than 1 user try to access it login but then its not working more after 1 to 2 mints

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public class clsMySqlConnection
{
    public MySqlConnection con = null;

    protected MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        if (con == null || con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
        }
        return (con);
    }
}

public class clsManagement : clsMySqlConnection
{
    public DataTable getData(string MySql)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd.CommandText = MySql;
        cmd.Connection = getConnection();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        return (dt);
    }

    public MySqlDataReader ExecuteActionQuery(string MySql)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = MySql;
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = getConnection();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return (rdr);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }

    }

    public int ExecuteDML(string MySql)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = MySql;
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = getConnection();
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full text of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new connection and return from `getConnection()` function.

```
protected MySqlConnection getConnection()
{
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
}
```

And use `con` variable in local scope.

Comment: public static MySqlConnection con = null;

    protected MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        if (con == null || con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
        }
        return (con);
    }

Comment: Thats the problem, remove this `public static`, make `con` variable in local scope in all functions.

Comment: still website stuck when more than 1 user access .

Comment: error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached. << this Error comes

Comment: Can you post updated code in question. It could be old connections get piled up in pool. Is it possible to restart server if its not in production environment?

Comment: Have you matched that function code with the code in this answer?

Comment: yeah i match i make MySqlConnection con public because i am using that in an other class  for close .